# How to get the data of a registry value in batch

Tags: batch-file, windows-registry

I'm trying to get the value of `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\everyoneincludeanonymous`. I've tried using `Reg Query` but no matter what I type it says "INVALID KEY NAME". Here is what I have tried:

```
REG QUERY Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\everyoneincludeanonymous /s
Reg Query "Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa' /v everyoneincludeanonymous`
```

But they all reply "INVALID KEY NAME".

I'm running Windows 10 Home.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax `Reg query /?` or visit [ss64.com/nt/reg.html](http://ss64.com/nt/reg.html) requires the computer/machine name to be preceeded with a double backslash.

So:

```
Reg Query "\\Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa' /v everyoneincludeanonymous
```

should do.